# Strange offset error in PHP

Tags: php

I am getting an error I cannot solve.

The error is:

```
Uninitialized string offset: 1
```

The code is:

```
if($play_count_within_45_minutes[1] > $play_history_old_over_45_minutes_ago[$i][1]){...}
```

The error is occurring on the `$play_count_within_45_minutes[1]` variable, because when I change the index to `0` (as in `$play_count_within_45_minutes[0]`), it works fine.

I had it display what the value would be, and it outputs fine, with this code:

```
print_r($play_count_within_45_minutes[1]);
```

The output is:

```
1.0E+80
```

The original variable declaration is:

```
$play_count_within_45_minutes = [0, 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000];
```

I don't think the number is too large, as I tried changing it `1` and I got the same error.

I found it has something to do with this loop (`print_r()` is in there as I was testing it, and it gives the same error):

```
for($i=0; $i <= (count($play_history_old_over_45_minutes_ago)-1); $i++ ){
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($play_count_within_45_minutes[1]);
    echo "<br>";
    if($play_count_within_45_minutes[1] > $play_history_old_over_45_minutes_ago[$i][1]){
        $play_count_within_45_minutes = $play_history_old_over_45_minutes_ago[$i][1];
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your PHP version? Declaring arrays by `$var = [];` did not occur until v5.4 http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php `As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].`

Comment: could you post the output of sizeof($play_count_within_45_minutes)?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15538676/2493918).

Comment: @Sean That's good information. I noticed that in the manual. I definitely checked it out by running `print_r` on the value to make sure it would read.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the reason I couldn't figure it out.

What I didn't know about the PHP errors is that it treats everything after the original `if` statement as the same line, so even though the error was on line 105, it kept telling me it was on 104.

However, I still don't know why changing the original `$play_count_within_45_minutes[1]` to `$play_count_within_45_minutes[0]` solved the problem. Nonetheless, that would have still had a problem.

The fixed code is:

```
for($i=0; $i <= (count($play_history_old_over_45_minutes_ago)-1); $i++ ){
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($play_count_within_45_minutes[1]);
    echo "<br>";
    if($play_count_within_45_minutes[1] > $play_history_old_over_45_minutes_ago[$i][1]){
        $play_count_within_45_minutes[1] = $play_history_old_over_45_minutes_ago[$i][1];
    }
}
```

It seems like a dumb error, but I really didn't know about PHP treating the entire line following the `if` statement as the same line.

Comment: Good you found out. Solving problems yourself will make you remember it better (at least I've had a couple of similar situations).

Comment: Definitely. This is my first super-complicated logic PHP program. I've learned a lot so far.